# Nested Datasets with FdQuery Firedac

Tags: firedac

how are you? Need to ask a question, when using `dbExpress`, it was possible to master detail with `clientDataSet` using `Nested DataSet`, where in `clientDataSet PAI`, I opened a new DataSet column (with data from the child table) and so I used to query and apply the data in the bank.

However,
When using Firedac with `FdQuery`, I couldn't find a way to do that, the only way I could do something similar is to use `fdSchemaAdapter` and make the relationship between `fdquerys` through `DataSources`.

Can anyone tell me if this option is supported by firedac?

**I didn't understand how to assemble SQL from parent table "SELECT * FROM {id Orders}" and how related to SQL from child table "SELECT * FROM {id Order Details}"**

Source: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Master-Detail_Relationship_(M/D)

Comment: Aren't you asking for [Master-Detail Relationship](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Master-Detail_Relationship_(M/D))?

Comment: Yes, it is a relationship master detail. But I would like firedac to be the same as DbExpress, where when opening a ClientDataSet with child relationships, that in the ClientDataSet Parent, it has a Child DataSet column.
All this process would like to do in firedac, but using only fdquery without having to use ClientDataSet.

Comment: If you are using an fdquery, just write the SQL text for the query to pull from both the master and detail tables

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but as I would use for query and also to apply the data with the same Fdquery, I wanted to see if it is possible to do this just like clientDataSet, because with only one data search, I can change and apply the data through ClientDataSet Parent only, which in my case would be using an Fdquery

Comment: @RicardoSchiaviniPanho, what is your database ? TFDQuery supports nested datasets for the databases supporting such data type, eg Oracle, PostgreSQL.